# Access standalone values in json responses

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, response

As a response to a request I have the following output:

```
{
    [
        "1545904980",             //val1
        "0.058",                  //val2
        "0.049",                  //val3
        "0.058",                  //val4
        "0.049",                  //val5
        "0.018",                  //val6
        "0.000945"                //val7
    ],
    [
        "1545904920",
        "0.058",
        "0.072",
        "0.072",
        "0.058",
        "0.103",
        "0.006986"
    ]
}
```

Let's say I want to access **val3** and thus ""0.049", this is what I use:

```py
    test = requests.get("url")

    # to load response into json we must convert response to string
    test_list = str(test.json())

    #before loading response into json we must convert '' string to "" type string.
    s_test = test_list.replace("\'", "\"")
    test_data = json.loads(s_test)
    
    for i in test_data:
        for j in i:
            print(i[2])
    pass
```

**EDIT:**

Every time I run this code it just runs but without error. I think it directly moves to "pass". Everything works fine if I just use

```py
    for i in test_data:
        print(i)
```

But that prints the whole JSON object which is not the goal. Any help on how to access those specific values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. I think you are looking for a blend of your two `for` loop attempts.

```
import json

s_test = '''
[
    ["1545904980", "0.058", "0.049", "0.058", "0.049", "0.018", "0.000945"],
    ["1545904920", "0.058", "0.072", "0.072", "0.058", "0.103", "0.006986"]
]
'''
test_data = json.loads(s_test)

for row in test_data:
    print(row[2])
```

Should give you:

```
0.049
0.072
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I tried it but it gave me single characters & not the data I was expecting. I checked the output of the object to be sure that there are no other data besides those numbers but did not find any.. Why would I get this type of output if it is not to be found in the original response?

Comment: Can you verify that the example represents your actual data. I am fairly sure the the example I posted produces the given result.

Comment: The data I gave is an example but the endpoints I am testing with are different.
This is the output when i use "print(test_data[i]":

[
['1566788400', '0.00456', '0.0045713', '0.0045713', '0.00456', '18866.13656796', '86.157820374417214'], 
['1566786600', '0.00456', '0.00456', '0.0045637', '0.0045599', '36199.78545767', '165.076784167255948']...]

Note that the response body still has more data but I left those out for Visuality.

Comment: if you print `test_data[i]` you likely get the full array entry for the i-th element. You want to take a closer look at my example or the one from @mathieu-troullier.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do this:

```python
import requests

response = requests.get("url")

data = response.json()

for row in data:
    print(row[2])
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but it gave me the error "KeyError: 2". I feel like this is not that hard but I can't see where I am messing up the code..

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
test = requests.get("url")
test_data = test['data']


for i in range(len(test_data)):
    for j in test_data[i]:
        if test_data[i]['dict_key'] == 'any_value':
            # do something here
        else:
            i = i + 1
```

This iterates over a list of dictionaries.